# Is the weakReference.get() method safe to call from multiple threads at the same time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is the `weakReference.get()` method safe to call from multiple `threads` 
at the same time?

The documentation says that

> Once an object has been determined to be  garbage collectable at that time it will atomically clear all weak  references to that
>   object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WeakReference.get()` when updated by the GC or it couldn't be updated by the GC thread. Otherwise, there would be a risk you could see an object which has previously been collected.

Note: As @Pillar may be suggesting, there is one operation which is not thread safe `clear()`, it is possible another thread might still `get()` the value after this is called.

Comment: You're basically saying that every reference variable is thread safe since GC needs to be able to modify it. That's not true. The memory model doesn't apply to GC threads in the same way as application threads.

Comment: @Pillar so you are saying that you can see objects after they have been moved or GCed?

Comment: @Pillar Let us come back to the topic

Comment: I'm saying that when GC moves an object and updates the value of a variable to a new location, that doesn't make that variable thread safe, even though program state is OK.

Comment: @Pillar I am not say it applies the same way, but the GC does need certain guarantees in order to function using additional threads.

Comment: @Pillar Would you agree that the operation of the GC must be thread safe?

Comment: @Pillar You are right that I shouldn't imply all operations are thread safe, see my updated answer.

Comment: I don't know anymore. I'll investigate some more.

Comment: I was looking at these resources: [discussion](http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/Thread-safety-of-WeakReference-get-method-td3363.html), [bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7190310), [solution](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2012-August/008190.html)